# Expressions in Visual studio for Date

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am building a report , in one of the column, I have to show the value as `__ Years __ Months`

I have Date of birth and other date (for example current date) . 
I made the code

```
=Int(DATEDIFF("m", Fields!ptnDateofBirth.Value ,Field current date / 12)) & " Years " & (DATEDIFF("mm", Fields!ptnDateofBirth.Value, Field current date  Mod 12)) & " months"
```

Expected result : it has to make difference of the Date of birth and the current date and to show the age in the format which I mentioned . But it shows an Error.

Comment: Please edit your post, use the code indent to show the code, add the right Tags, include the exception message, Visual Studio is an IDE not a programming language. Check [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thank you.

Comment: Sure , noted and updated